# Component is Not a Known Element - Multi Module Application

Tags: angular, typescript

I think I have an issue with how I've got my modules set up, because I can't use any shared components across any of my modules.

Basically, I have a Core module and then a Feature module. The Core module contains all of the components that I want to be shared across a multitude of Feature modules. The FeatureModule is importing the CoreModule.

I have a component, `PageSectionComponent` that I want to display on a dashboard page within the FeatureModule. However, when I try to use the selector, I get the `page-section is not a known element` error.

**FilePath**

```
src
   - components
      - site-layout.component.html
      - site-layout.component.ts
   - modules
      - core
         - core-routing.module.ts
         - core.module.ts
      - feature
         - pages
            - dashboard-page.component.html
            - dashboard-page.component.ts
         - components
            - page-section.component.html
            - page-section.component.ts
         - feature-routing.module.ts
         - feature.module.ts
```

**feature.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FeatureRoutingModule } from './feature-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    FeatureRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

**core.module.ts** - imports both the SiteLayout and the PageSection.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SiteLayoutComponent } from 'app/components';
import { CoreRoutingModule } from './core-routing.module';

import { PageSectionComponent } from '@feature/components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageSectionComponent,
    SiteLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    PageSectionComponent,
    SiteLayoutComponent
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

I think that my issue is within my routing. I have a `SiteLayoutComponent` that I'm trying to utilize to wrap pages from both the Core and the Feature modules. So my `FeatureRoutingComponent` ends up looking like this, where all paths have the `SiteLayoutComponent`, and then get the specific Dashboard, or whatever, component injected based on path.

**feature-routing.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SiteLayoutComponent } from '@components/layouts/site-layout.component';
import { DashboardPageComponent } from '@feature/pages';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
      { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardPageComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule { }
```

At the moment, `SiteLayoutComponent` just contains the router-outlet.

**site-layout.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So here's where I start running into trouble. On the `DashboardPageComponent`, I'm attempting to place a 'PageSectionComponent'.

**dashboard-page.component.html**

```
<page-section></page-section>
```

And this is where I end up with the error stating that `page-section` is not a known element.

I was reading up on multi-module applications, and from what I was able to understand, it seems like all I should have to do is put the `PageSectionComponent` into the `CoreModule`'s imports + exports, and then import `CoreModule` within the `FeatureModule`... but it obviously isn't working.

At the moment, the only guess I have is that because the Site-Layout is a shareable component, and is referenced directly inside `feature-routing.module.ts` AND `core.module.ts`, that it's losing scope on the imported `PageSectionComponent` somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, I can't find where you declare your DashboardPageComponent... I think that you need to make this declaration first.

try something like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FeatureRoutingModule } from './feature-routing.module';
import { DashboardPageComponent } from './feature.module';
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';

    @NgModule({
      declarations:[
         DashboardPageComponent 
      ],
      imports: [
        CoreModule,
        FeatureRoutingModule
      ],
      export: [
        DashboardPageComponent
       ]
    })
    export class FeatureModule {}
```

You can't forget of made import component.

I would also think better of this modularization, it is extremely confusing.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that. That absolutely fixed it. 

And agreed on my modularization effort - I'm trying to create a solution template thats more reusable, so this is my first go at it. I'm eventually going to re-do this entirely after I learn a little bit more about how it all fits together.

Comment: Great!!! 
When we declare many components in a unique module, this module "js" compiled stays very big.